# Insert simple + double quote MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, quotes, insertion

Considering this table

```
CREATE TABLE name
( nom VARCHAR(255))
```

How could i insert a string with simple + double quote like : 'it's a  "string"' inside my table

```
Insert into name values (`it's "string"`)
```

This doesn't work actually.
Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `'` as string delimiters and backslash to escape special chars:

```
Insert into name values ('it\'s \"string\"')
```

Comment: I knew about escaping, my problem was that I have many string from à cdv file. You are not really responding to my answer but you give me an idea. Thanks

Comment: Probably, you should edit your question then. I don't see anything about a "cdv file" in your question

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
CREATE TABLE name
( nom VARCHAR(255));

set @str = "it\'s \"string\"";
insert into name values(@str);
```

You have to use `\` before single and double quotes.

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2c372/1)